# prove  (a+b)*=a*(ba*)*  

Tags: formal-languages, automata-theory

formal language and automata theory

regular expessions
 (a+b)* =a*(ba*)*
please answer
I want the proof
thank you

Comment: Welcome to MO! Please read FAQs and 'how to ask' to see how to phrase a question that would be appreciated here. Your question is difficult to understand; perhaps somebody can infer what the symbols ought to mean but still it would be nicer to have it spelled out so that more people can appreciate your question.  

Comment: Quid, the question has completely standard notation. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). But nevertheless, the expression in the title is different from the expression in the question itself, because of some misplaced asterisks. 

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: right, so replace 'perhaps somebody can infer' by 'while some will know'. I think I still maintain the rest of my comment.   

Answer (score 2):

Your title expression $(a+b)^\ast=a^\ast(ba^\ast)^\ast$ is not true, since the right side allows the instance $b$ alone, but every nonempty instance on the left must have at least one $a$.

Meanwhile, the expression in the body of your question $(a+b)=a(ba^\ast)^\ast$ is not true, since all instances of the left expression have only one $b$, but on the right, we can have $abbbb$.

Comment: Joel, it seems the notation might not be as standard as you and I thought.  To me, the LHS in the title, $(a+b)^*$, means the set of those sequences obtained by concatenating any number of sequences, each of which is either just $a$ or just $b$.  In other words, it's the set of all words on the alphabet `$\{a,b\}$`, and these need not contain any $a$. So, on my understanding of the notation, the title formula is correct.  

Comment: Apparently Wikipedia uses | to mean what I would write as $+$.

Comment: I haven't seen $+$ used to mean $\mid$, but I have seen it appearing as an exponent, as in $(a^+b)^\ast$. 

Comment: the question was given in one of my exams. 

Comment: Joel, I've also seen it used as an exponent, with the meaning of "concatenate any non-zero number of copies".

Comment: Yes, that is also how I interpret it, and this is what Wikipedia says for the unexponent version as well. So $a^+=a+=aa^\ast$. 

Comment: Meanwhile, we learned it is the title that is on an exam and a proof is asked. So, Andreas Blass's reading is the 'right' one?  

Comment: W* means 0 or more copies of W concatenated.  
W+ means 1 or more copies of W concatenated.
There are some books on formal languages
which use * in the sense of +, but when talking
about regular expressions and Kleene's algebra,
I believe the above has been in use since before
1960.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design"
Paseman, 2012.11.10

Comment: With Andreas's reading of $+$ to mean $|$, which I think is nonstandard as Gerhard says, then the title equation is true, since both expressions can generate any word in $a$ and $b$. 

Comment: Further, my reading agrees with Andreas and disagrees with the answer given by Joel above
(at the rough time of this writing).  Gerhard
"Information Version Control Made Difficult"
Paseman, 2012.11.10

Comment: (Of course Joel would post a comment between my two.)  Gerhard "Meaning Of Time Changes Temporally" Paseman, 2012.11.10

Comment: Gerhard, your reading is the same as mine, not Andreas, because he is saying that $(a+b)$ means $(a\mid b)$, which is not what you said, since $(a+b)$ should mean any nonzero number of $a$'s followed by a $b$. 

Comment: Meanwhile, Wikipedia says, "Many textbooks use the symbols ∪, +, or ∨ for alternation instead of the vertical bar". 

Comment: Perhaps one could say the notation is a (standard)^+ notation, not so clear how many there are. :) But, I have to admit, I learned quite a bit from this question, so somehow I start to like it.   

Comment: @Joel, many computer scientists use + for union because the set of regular languages is a semiring with union as addition.  The $+$ is also used in exponents to indicate that the subsemigroup is to be generated instead of the submonoid (for which * uses).